# "If he gets killed" - does the "get" here represents the passive?

Tags: get-passive

I know that the "get" word has so many meanings and I try to figure out what function it has in the sentence:

> "If he gets killed"

I know "get" can be used to create a passive (so without, would it be "if he is killed"?)
Or is it the change of state/condition?

Comment: 'Passive' in grammar doesn't imply a necessarily peaceful transition / state. This is the get-passive, as in 'When we get married ...'.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is a way of forming a passive. A nice overview of using get to form passives is [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/get-passive).